# Verificar coluna vazia mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com problema de verificar quais colunas estão vazias no `mysql`. Estou usando o `COALESCE` mas ele so verifica a primeira coluna da sequência:

```
COALESCE(column1, column2, column3...) AS values
```

Se `column1` estiver vazio ele retorna, mas se `column1` estiver preenchida e um dos demais estiverem vazia ele não retorna qual esta vazia, ele so verifica a primeira coluna. Como posso verificar qual coluna esta vazia independente da posição?

Comment: Mas isto é exatamente o que se espera que a função coalesce faça, que retorne o primeiro elemento não null da lista. Creio que você precise fazer um teste coluna a coluna.

Comment: Hum, vou tentar usar o CASE WHEN juntamente com o COALESCE, será que funcionaria @anonimo ?

Comment: Creio que um IFNULL(columnx, 'NULL') para cada coluna seja melhor. Talvez a interface que está utilizando possa ser configurada para exibir a string 'NULL' (ou qualquer string de sua escolha) quando o conteúdo do campo for NULL.

Comment: Irei ver sobre o IFNULL @anonimo